# Diffrent results for the image and screenshot of the image

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-vision, react-native-image-picker

I am using an object localizer with react native image picker to get coordinates of objects within an image. When I send the image by taking a photo with the android device the results I get are not accurate but when I take the screenshot of the photo and send it the results are almost perfect. Why might this be the case and how can I fix it?

The interesting thing is when I use the android studio emulator and send photos without taking screenshots of them the results are correct too. I have read that there are recommended image sizes for these operations however I could not find one for the object localizer.

Edit: I have found that when I take a screen shot the image resolution is equal to my devices width and height however when  I take photo  it uses cameras resolution.To give an example right now when I take a photo its resolution is 4032x2268 and resolution of said images screen shot is 1080x2220 which is the resolution I use for my android device.İs there any way to set cameras resolution to same as devices resolution?

Comment: Are you asking if you can change camera resolution?

Comment: Yes,I would like to set up camera resolution manually with code.I am using image picker but any library is welcome.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868954/android-opencv-how-to-set-camera-resolution-when-using-camerabridgeviewbase/17872107 Maybe?

Comment: Yeah that is what I was looking for, thanks.